# Самая длинная строка в List

Tags: java, массивы

> Задача:
>
> 1. Создай список строк.
> 2. Считай с клавиатуры 5 строк и добавь в список.
> 3. Используя цикл, найди самую длинную строку в списке.
> 4. Выведи найденную строку на экран.
> 5. Если таких строк несколько, выведи каждую с новой строки.

Как правильно вывести только самую длинную строку из списка и те - которые будут равны ее длине?

```
package com.javarush.test.level07.lesson06.task02;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        String s = reader.readLine();
        list.add(s);
    }

    int max = list.get(0).length();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

        if (list.get(i).length() > max){

            max = list.get(i).length();
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }else if (list.get(i).length() == max){

            max = list.get(i).length();
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: не задан вопрос

Comment: Длину строк можно проверять сразу при вводе, чтобы не бегать лишний раз по списку

Comment: заведите ещё одну переменную, которая хранит индекс строки с максимальной длиной и всё

Comment: Ещё лучше завести список самых длинных строк. Как только попалась строка длиннее, список очищается/уничтожается и заполняется заново.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
       strings.add(reader.readLine());

Collections.sort(strings, (s1, s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length());
int length = strings.get(0).length();
for (String string : strings)
     if (length == string.length())
         System.out.println(string);
     else
         break;
```

Comment: Только break не надо, иначе если будет несколько строк с одинаковой максимальной длиной то их все не выведет.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на код. Я сортирую строки по длине, первая строка в списке оказывается самая длинная. Затем беру ее длину и присваиваю переменной, затем итерируюсь до тех пор пока длины совпадают. Код корректен

Comment: По задаче нужно вывести ВСЕ строки с максимальной длиной. В вашем случае будет выведена только самая первая строка, а что если будет две (или больше) с такой же длиной?

Comment: запустите код в дебаггере и посмотрите как он работает.

Comment: Всё правильно, я ошибался.

Answer (score 0):

```
Еще более подробный вариант:

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            String s = reader.readLine();

            strings.add(0, s);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            if (strings.get(i).length() > strings.get(0).length()) {

                strings.set(0, strings.get(i));
            }

        }

        System.out.println(strings.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: К сути это конечно не относиться, но зачем делать отступ после каждой строк? Выглядит ужасно.

Answer (score -1):

что--то вроде такого:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    //Fill list
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        String s = reader.readLine();
        list.add(s);
    }

    //Find largest string(s)
    String max = Collections.max(list , Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()));

    ArrayList<string> maxLengthStrs = new ArrayList<string>;

    foreach (var str in list)
    {
       if(str.length == max)
       {
          maxLengthStrs.Add(str);
          System.out.println(str);
       }
    }

    //maxLengthStrs -- строка(и) с наибольшей длинной
}
```

Comment: Текст вашего поста выглядит ответоподобным (какой-то код, что-то там делает, явного спама нет и т.п.) но вообще-то этот код не решает задачу топикстартера: строк может быть несколько и вывести нужно не одну максимальную, а все максимальные. А у вас условие "больше" вместо "больше либо равно" и только одна строка хранится.

Comment: пофиксил все что нужно было.